# Dynamic "where" in custom ParseQueryAdapter

Tags: android, dynamic, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com as framework to populate a ListView. My Adapter looks like this:

```
    public ItemsQueryAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery Query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Item");
            LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder().
                    include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(currentLatLng, currentRadius, 0)).
                    include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(currentLatLng, currentRadius, 90)).
                    include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(currentLatLng, currentRadius, 180)).
                    include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(currentLatLng, currentRadius, 270)).build();
            itemsQuery.whereWithinGeoBox("location", new ParseGeoPoint(latLngBounds.southwest.latitude, latLngBounds.southwest.longitude), new ParseGeoPoint(latLngBounds.northeast.latitude, latLngBounds.northeast.longitude));
            itemsQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt");
            itemsQuery.include("user");
            return itemsQuery;
        }
    });
}
```

And my ListView being populated like this:

```
    itemsQueryAdapter = new ItemsQueryAdapter(getActivity());
    ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    listView.setAdapter(itemsQueryAdapter);
    itemsQueryAdapter.loadObjects();
```

The problem I now have is that inside the custom adapter, both currentLatLng and currentRadius can change and therefore need to be dynamically "loaded" on each loadObjects() I do. Is there a way to do this?

Regards,
D.